# driver.switchTo().Alerts() in selenium webdriver using java NOT working in IE11 when executed in perfecto

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I will let you know the exact scenario of the issue that I am facing right now while working on IE 11 browser in Win 10 using Perfecto.

Scenario: A webpage has a frame and that frame inturn has a table consisting of lot of data. One such data happens to be a "Delete" link and upon clicking it, I get a pop up of "Are you sure?" with Yes or No buttons.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frameID);
```

Challenge: `driver.switchTo().Alert()` is not working in Windows 10 - IE11 browser in Perfecto where as it works in CHrome browser of same OS combinations:

Solutions Tried:
1) 
`((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.confirm=function(){return true;}");`

and many such trail and error methods in javaScriptExecutor.

Error faced: Since "driver" instance is inside Frame, when we execute window.confirm or window.alert, I am facing NullPointerException.

2) Using Robot class for blind ENTER key.

```
Robot rb = new Robot();
rb.delay(2000);
rb.pressKey(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
rb.releaseKey(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Error Faced: Doesn't work. Pop up stays right there.

3) `driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`

Error faced - closes the pop up and control goes to the webpage without deleting the record which is not the functionality.

4) `driver.switchTo().ActiveElement()`

Error faced:  throws WebDriverException.

Please help in providing a solution.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4djP.jpg)

NOTE: Same piece of code works in chrome browser. Issue is with IE11 when run in Perfecto.

Comment: I can have a look with IE 10, but I am not sure about Perfecto environment. Any tailor-made environment? Thanks

Comment: You need to post snapshot of alert() you are having

Comment: @kushal... Thats on a client network and I cant post it...Pls refer to the image description that I have provided in the question. I hope it helps

Comment: That is a pop not an alert, check if you're able to inspect elements on it.